# Error while adding NavigationContainer in react native with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

When I define my `NavigationContainer` on separate file I get following error:

```
'NavigationContainer' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof NavigationContainer'?
```

But when I define it in `App.tsx` works.

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function AppNavigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Routes.SPLASH}
        component={SplashScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default AppNavigator
```

What is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed file extension to `tsx` and error gone.